# Writing to a cell based on todays date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am learning coding in Sheets, and have already jigsawed together a couple of games (based off very limited coding knowledge. Very fun to see it come together

Next task: 
I am logging my hours spent doing "Growth" things (like learning, exercise, work etc.) vs "Leisure" things (like TV, games, FB scrolling etc). Up until now I just scroll down to today's date and add in the numbers manually. Would be fun to have a button at the top of my sheet that just adds hours to the "Growth" or "Leisure" cells for today.

I have used formulae in the cell G371 to reveal the A1 notation of my target cell, hoping I can use this info in a script to write to that cell:

=substitute(Cell("address",vlookup(A1,A2:D367,3)),"$","")

Where cell A1 contains =today()
and A2:A367 are all the dates in the year.
and columns C and D hold numbers for growth and leisure respectively.

Then I tried this code to try to see how to write to a cell. I realise I am probably missing some very fundamental knowledge...

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cellname = ss.getRange('G371')     // makes cellname refer to G371
  var input = cellname.getValue()        // makes 'input' return the contents of G371, in today's case its 'C120'
  var test = ss.getRange(input)          // hopefully reads 'C120' instead of "input"

  test.setValue(1)                       // setting value to 1 for now, as I'm just testing cell 
                                         //   referencing. later I will work on figuring out the 
                                         //   math for the buttons. I'm not there yet.
```

So it didn't work. apparently the problem is with `ss.getRange(input)` but I don't know what to do about that.

So my question is how to write to a cell that is named in another cell?

hope it makes sense

Thanks!

PS Here is a copy of the sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KkoCb8kY1XICMeB9bx65HXsldCS-fa75xJCaU52WGg8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you please share a copy of your spreadsheet (free of sensitive information), as well as the outcome you expect?

Comment: Copy of spreadsheet added to bottom of the original post, thanks.

outcome I intend is written in the second paragraph above. I'll try say it another way:

To have a button that will add a number to a target cell, the target cell is changes depending on what day it is, as journal entries go into the current day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula in the cell might be messing with the value you retrieve. To make sure that does not happen, you can use [getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue) instead of `getValue()`.

#### Another way:

Also, if you just want to retrieve the cell where to write today's growth (or leisure), you don't need to follow this roundabout way of creating a formula in another cell to reference this one. You can do this instead (check comments):

```js
function todayGrowthCell() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "d/M"); // Format today's date as in spreadsheet, in order to compare
  var firstRow = 2; // Row where days start
  var column = 3; // Column C (Growth)
  var dates = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 366).getDisplayValues().map(row => row[0]); // Retrieve columns with dates (its display value, in order to compare with today's date, which is formatted accordingly)
  var row = dates.indexOf(date) + firstRow; // Today's row
  var cell = sheet.getRange(row, column); // Today's growth cell
  cell.setValue(1); // Set value to today's growth cell
}
```